# jQuery used in materialize only works through console

Tags: jquery, meteor, materialize

So im trying to use some features of materialize like the material box: [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/media.html).

The jQuery is supposed to load automatically. In the "Initialization" part of that page in the link it shows the jQuery that can be manually added. I tried adding that to the bottom of `Meteor.isClient` and it also doesnt work. The only way i can get the materialbox feature to work properly is to open the console and enter the the jQuery manually-`$('.materialboxed').materialbox();`

After that i am able to click on the images and have the materialbox feature work properly. Any idea whats going on here? How can this be fixed?

Edit: Note this also happens with things like materialize's side-menu which is initialized by: `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();` this also does not work unless the statement is enetered into the console.

Comment: did you try `Template.templateName.onRendered(function(){$(".button-collapse").sideNav();$('.materialboxed').materialbox();})` ??

Comment: like this? http://prntscr.com/6z16lr and 'check' is printed out. I think this has something to do with rendering the pictures that contain the `materialboxed` class in a {{#each}} loop. If i take away the the loop and add a static image url, it would work.

Comment: Ok so you are using an {{#each}} can i see the template and the helper?

Comment: template: http://prntscr.com/6z189h helper: http://prntscr.com/6z18hb

Comment: Try with this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/QYWDBck8vsQ97YY8k/Leaderboard) just copy/paste the code

Comment: ='( using subscriptionsReady didnt seem to change anything